# Automapper and Generic Mapping

Tags: automapper

Is there anyway to condense this down with automapper?  It is just getting to big.

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<Headline>, PagedResult<HeadlineModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<Event>, PagedResult<EventModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<GymCourt>, PagedResult<GymCourtModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<Gym>, PagedResult<GymModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<EventGymCourt>, PagedResult<EventGymCourtModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<Division>, PagedResult<DivisionModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<Team>, PagedResult<TeamModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<DivisionTeam>, PagedResult<DivisionTeamModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<MemberTeam>, PagedResult<MemberTeamModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<TeamCoach>, PagedResult<TeamCoachModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<DivisionAsset>, PagedResult<DivisionAssetModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<EventAsset>, PagedResult<EventAssetModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<Event>, PagedResult<ApiEvent>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<Price>, PagedResult<PriceModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<DivisionPrice>, PagedResult<DivisionPriceModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<EventPrice>, PagedResult<EventPriceModel>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<Division>, PagedResult<ApiDivision>>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<Data.Entities.Player>, PagedResult<PlayerModel>>();
```

Answer (score 12):

What you can do is to use an extension method.  If you add this class:

```
public static class MappingExtensions
{
    public static IMappingExpression<TSrc, TDest> IncludePagedResultMapping<TSrc, TDest>(this IMappingExpression<TSrc, TDest> expression)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedResult<TSrc>, PagedResult<TDest>>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.HasMoreResults, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.HasMoreResults))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.NextPage, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.NextPage));

        return expression;
    }
}
```

then you can include the paged mappings as part of your entity to model mappings, viz:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Headline, HeadlineModel>().IncludePagedResultMapping();
Mapper.CreateMap<Event, EventModel>().IncludePagedResultMapping();
Mapper.CreateMap<GymCourt, GymCourtModel>().IncludePagedResultMapping();
Mapper.CreateMap<Player, PlayerModel>().IncludePagedResultMapping();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no build in support in Automapper for custom mapper registration conventions, but you can DRY it up a little with some reflection:

```
var mappingDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
{
    {typeof (Headline), typeof (HeadlineModel)},
    {typeof (Event), typeof (EventModel)},
    //...
};
foreach (var sourceType in mappingDictionary.Keys)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap(
       typeof (PagedResult<>).MakeGenericType(sourceType),
       typeof (PagedResult<>).MakeGenericType(mappingDictionary[sourceType]));
}
```

Or if you always follow your convention `Headline` -> `HeadlineModel` etc. With some more reflection you don't need to build up the mapping by hand:

```
var modelAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HeadlineModel));
var otherAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Headline));
foreach (var destinationType in modelAssembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.Namespace == "ModelNaspace" && t.Name.EndsWith("Model")))
{
    var destinationName = destinationType.Name.Replace("Model", "");
    var sourceType = otherAssembly.GetTypes()
        .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Namespace == "OtherNamespace" && t.Name == destinationName);

    if (sourceType == null)
    {
        //log warning
        continue;
    }

    Mapper.CreateMap(
       typeof (PagedResult<>).MakeGenericType(sourceType),
       typeof (PagedResult<>).MakeGenericType(destinationType));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid not. At some point of time you will have to tell AutoMapper about your class mappings.

If your are looking to consolidate your Global.aspx (assuming you are using AutoMapper in Asp.Net), you may want to try Bootstrapper.

More on Bootstrapper: http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/02/17/use-bootstrapper-in-your-asp-net-mvc-application-and-reduce-code-smell.aspx